# Capturing variable value from URL in PHP which is best, $_GET or $_REQUEST?

Tags: php, url

URL: http://stackcomplete.com?message=143

need to capture `message` variable value in PHP, i was confused which one is best `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`

1. `$_GET['message']`

or

1. `$_REQUEST['message']`

Comment: From URL? GET, GET and GET. REQUEST is not only url, its a combination of multiple arrays so avoid that

Comment: `$_REQUEST` contains both `$_POST` and `$_GET`, while `$_GET` is just `$_GET` and same for `$_POST`, so use `$_GET['message']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with `$_GET`

`$_REQUEST` ***holds an associative array*** that by default contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.

Since you know that the parameter will be URL based. `$_GET` will suffice.